# Write the implementation of an output operator overload outside the .h file

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, output

I have the following C++ Header File:

```
namespace big_numbers
{
    class bigint
    {
    private:
        // private data
    public:
        // constructors and other methods
        friend ostream & operator<<( ostream & out, const bigint & data )
        {
            out << data.str();
            return out;
        }
    };
}
```

This is the only way that I found to declare and define the `<<` operator for my class, to be used like so

```
bigint number("12345");
cout << number;
```

I tried some other things but they don't work. My application does not compile. How to overload this operator writing the declaration in a header file and the definition in a source file?

After modifying the code as in @DanielFrey answer, my IDE (Microsoft Visual Studio 2013) reports the following error:

```
Error   5   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl BigNumbers::operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class BigNumbers::bigint const &)" (??6BigNumbers@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV12@ABVbigint@0@@Z) referenced in function _wmain  E:\Applications\BigNumbers\test\test.obj    test_console
```

Comment: It might help if you could provide the errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
// header
namespace big_numbers
{
    class bigint
    {
    private:
        // private data
    public:
        // constructors and other methods
        friend ostream & operator<<( ostream & out, const bigint & data );
    };
}
```

and

```
// implementation
#include "bignum.hh"

namespace big_numbers
{
    ostream & operator<<( ostream & out, const bigint & data )
    {
        out << data.str();
        return out;
    }
}
```

(given the correct includes in both header and implementation file...)

Comment: is it required to use `.hh`? I've seen some kind of tending to this extension on some websites

Comment: @Victor You can also use `.hpp` or even `.h`, the extension doesn't really matter.

Comment: @Victor You need to actually compile the implementation file and *link* with it. Have you added it to your project? (I'm not using VC++/VS)

Comment: I don't know what is the problem since every method's implementation works, but this doesn't.

Comment: @Victor The above is the correct **code**, the problem seems to be in the project settings. Hope someone who uses VS can help you...

Comment: I think I found where the problem is. I will try it tomorroe when I am in front of my computer and accept the answer.

Answer (score 3):

To get around msvc linking issues:

```
class X {
    public:
    std::ostream& write(std::ostream&) const;
};

inline std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& s, const X& x) {
   return x.write(s);
}
```

Comment: @Yakk A friend operator declared and defined in X is too much magic.